# Tomcat server unable to start

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, mariadb

I have a maven project which I need to run. I am using MariaDB. But when I run the project, it is not able to find the maria db driver. I'm getting below error:

```
{"timestamp":"2020-09-16 13:38:14.453","level":"ERROR","thread":"main","logger":"org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter","message":"Error starting Tomcat context. 
Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. 
Message: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]:
 Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: 
Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint]: 
Factory method 'healthEndpoint' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'capitaLandAdapterConfiguration': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'hikariDataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: 
Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Cannot load driver class: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver ","context":"default"}
```

application.properties has

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
```

and pom has

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

What else is it I'm missing?

Comment: probably failed to load mariadb-java-client, run `mvn install` or maven reimport then try agian.

Comment: Already done that successfully